# Is the maximum radius of a balloon, which is attached to the faster balloon inflator, smaller than that attached to the slower one?

Tags: forces, material-science

It's occurred to me many times that if a bubble-gum is inflated very fast, it would explode when its size is not much large while blowing up slowly can make it bigger.

Now, suppose that two similar balloons are attached to two different balloon-inflating machines. Does my experience show that the maximum radius (before the explosion) of the balloon, which is attached to the faster balloon inflator, is smaller than that attached to the slower one?!

Answer (score 2):

It is due to the development of the undistributed high-stress area at selective points. It can be thought of the same as a rope hanging from a knot. Now if pulled with high force immediately high impulse is generated which and the rope instead of completely transferring the stress as tension reaches its maximum breaking point near the end being pulled and breaks. Whereas if it is pulled slowly and slowly forced is increased to the the force in previous case then it will break after a long time or even might not break for that force.

Comment: I've edited the question. Indeed, I knew your remarks. According to your comments, is your answer to my question affirmative?

Comment: I'm not sure the rope analogy is really correct. Tension exists throughout the entire rope - you can't pull just the bottom of a rope with force F without the entire rope feeling that force. I don't see any reason why the rope will snap close to where you pull it; it will snap at whatever point along the rope happens to be weakest. In fact, a hanging rope will generally snap at the *top*, since that part has the additional tension of the weight of the rope.

Comment: It is correct as impulsive force is being created and the moment it will exceed the limiting value of rope it will break.

Comment: Suppose the rope breaks under tension F. You pull the rope with slightly less force than that, F-e, and the rope pulls back with force F-e. Now you increase the strength of your pull to F. If the rope pulls back with F-e, the tension is only still F-e and the rope accelerates downward but doesn't break. That's not what happens, the rope pulls back with force F (everywhere), so the tension is F (everywhere) and the rope breaks (somewhere, but not necessarily at the bottom). You're saying tension varies throughout a massless rope when you pull on it?

Comment: There is limit to tension acting on element by its surrounding elements. If downward force is way higher than the maximum tension above memebers can provide at a time, then it will straight away break at that time. If slowly then it will keep maintaining tension equal to force till the time it starts deforming and ultimately break

Comment: What you are saying is just when you are giving it time to have tension to cancel on both sides to keep element without moving

Answer (score 0):

Bubblegum is viscoelastic: apply a stress to it very gradually, and it will slowly stretch out without breaking. apply the same stress to it suddenly, and it will snap.